# "Does not contain a definition" Error on method in interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface that is structured like this

```
public interface IDataContextAsync : IDataContext
{
    void DisableGlobalFilter(string filterName);
}
```

I have a class the uses the interface like this

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IObjectState
{
    private readonly IDataContextAsync _context;

    public Repository(IDataContextAsync context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void DisableGlobalFilter(string filterName)
    {
        _context.DisableGlobalFilter(filterName);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following Error

> 'Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContextAsync' does not contain a
>   definition for 'DisableGlobalFilter' and no extension method
>   'DisableGlobalFilter' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContextAsync' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

What's strange is that Visual Studio shows intelisense as correctly. I can also "Go To Definition" from the class to the interface correctly.

Comment: Do you have any other compiler errors? Are these in different assemblies?

Comment: Try rebuilding.. And maybe restarting VS.

Comment: The Class is in a project and the interface is in a different project. However, i have the class's project referencing the other. There are other errors however they are all in regard to the missing assembly from this error

Comment: I restarted VS and Rebuilt. No luck

Comment: Is `IDataContextAsync:DisableGlobalFilter()` actually implemented somewhere ?

Comment: Yes it is implemented in the classes that use the interface

Comment: It is practically guaranteed that if you take the time to create a concise, complete code example that reproduces the error, you will discover yourself what is causing the error. If not, you can at least then post that code example so that someone else can point out the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Really cheap way of diagnosing such problem (since you seem to have code for both) is to simply rename interface to something else (you should be easily roolback such change later using your source control system). Depending on how error changes you can see if you completely missed some dependency (like instead of project dependency you took dependency on DLL or something strange like that).

Answer (score 0):

Fair warning: I'm not a C# guy, but please consider the following anyway.

You're trying to call a method that doesn't exist.

`DisableGlobalFilter()` is *declared* in your`IDataContextAsync` interface, but it's not *defined* anywhere.  The fact that you incidentally happen to have a `DisableGlobalFilter()` method in the `Repository` class doesn't change it: this method is calling `_context.DisableGlobalFilter()`, `_context` is an instance of `IDataContextAsync`, which, as far as we can tell by looking at the code you posted, is just an interface.

At this point, `IDataContextAsync::DisableGlobalFilter()` is an abstract / pure virtual method.

You need to create a class that actually *implements* the `IDataContextAsync` interface (including `DisableGlobalFilter()`), then create an instance of that class, and pass this instance as an argument to your `Repository<TEntity>()` constructor, in the part of the code that is not shown in your post.

Comment: If this answer can be improved in any way, please feel free to edit it, or just let me know.  Downvoting without a reason doesn't contribute to the quality of this contribution.

Comment: As stated in my comments above I did in fact create an implementation of the interface. I included the specified function in that class.

Comment: Well then please, by all means post this implementation, because I can't see any definition of `IDataContextAsync::DisableGlobalFilter()` anywhere in your code, and _that_ is the function you're calling from `Repository<TEntity>::DisableGlobalIdentifier()` (that's precisely what your compiler is complaining about btw: `"'[...].IDataContextAsync' does not contain a definition for 'DisableGlobalFilter'"`).